# Jetpack Compose delete TextField content with icon

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to make a custom TextField where the text gets deleted when the right icon is pressed. The problem with the following code is that the textFieldValue.text is a val, so it can't be reassigned.

So far the only solution I have found is to recompose the entire TextField sending "" as the text. Is there a better way to achieve this?

```
var textFieldValue by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver)
    { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }

    MyTextField(
        text = textFieldValue,
        onValueChange = {
            textFieldValue = it
        },
        leftIconClickable = { /*Do nothing*/ },
        rightIconClickable = { textFieldValue.text  = "" }
    )
```

(At this point this textField has almost the same code as the TextField of Jetpack Compose, the main difference being that it also receives 2 clickables for the icons)

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried performing a `copy()`?

```
rightIconClickable = { textFieldValue = textFieldValue.copy(text = "") }
```

Here's a sample of a `TextField` using `TextFieldValue` with a simple `Button` where I `copy()` the current `TextFieldValue` instance, re-assigning it to the same variable, and it clears the `TextField`.

```
var textFieldValue by rememberSaveable(stateSaver = TextFieldValue.Saver) {
    mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(""))
}


Column {

    TextField(
        value = textFieldValue,
        onValueChange = {
            textFieldValue = it
        }
    )

    Button(onClick = {
        textFieldValue =  textFieldValue.copy(text = "")}) {
    }
}
```